# Windows 10 can't replace a deleted file on some Android devices' data directory

Tags: android, windows, usb, mtp, wpd

I'm running into an issue and can't find anything online to help me.

I have two Android devices: Samsung S20 and Meta Quest 2 connected to a PC running Windows 10.

I'm developing a Windows app that needs to exchange files with an Android portable device via USB. Since a recent Android OS update, app's access to non private (i.e. outside of Android/data/com.MyCompany.MyApp) directories is highly restricted, I am using the app's private directory to store the files.

But, on my Samsung phone, using either my desktop App (WPD libraries) or Windows Explorer, if I navigate to `device\Internal shared storage\Android\data\com.MyCompany.MyApp\files` it is not possible to delete a file and copy a new one with the same name. But it works on the Quest 2.

In other words, navigating to `device\Internal storage\Android\data\com.MyCompany.MyApp\files` I can delete the existing `File.txt` file, but I will not be able to copy or create a new file named `File.txt`, unless I physically disconnect the phone and connect it again. I do not get this behaviour on the Quest 2. Funny thing is, I was getting it a few months ago, but not anymore.

I have tried using copy\paste, drag and drop, copying the file to the parent directory and dragging it to the desired child directory, spamming F5, closing and re-opening Windows Explorer, restarting the WPD desktop app, ... nothing works except physically disconnecting the USB cable and plugging it back in. Feels like it's some sort of file cache issue.

I understand the restrictions on the Android\data directory. But this behaviour doesn't make sense and I can't seem to find a fix.

Has anyone experienced this and found a solution?

Comment: `Since a recent Android OS update, app's access to non private(..) directories is highly restricted` Well no. Every app can create files in all public directories on external storage.

Comment: `developing an Android app that needs to exchange files with a Windows computer ` After reading your post we know that not your app is exchanging files but someone on a Windows computer.

Comment: `but I will not be able to copy or create a new file named File.txt, ` Unclear. Who is I? Your app or the one on the Windows PC.

Comment: Sorry if the original post is not clear. What I mean is that I have a desktop App that needs to manage files on an Android portable device (phone or VR headset). 

The files on the Android device preferably wouldn't be in the Android public folders (Pictures, Downloads,...) but in a separate directory. Either the private app directory (com.MyCompany.MyApp) or some place else. 

I don't differentiate the desktop app file management behaviour from the Windows user actions in Windows Explorer because the results are the same.

Comment: Of course i ment your Android app.